# Is it possible to use an HTTPClient with Windows authentication within an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

Is it possible to specify Windows credentials to `HttpClient` within an AWS Lambda function?

For example:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var content = new StringContent("<test>test</test>", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://someurl", "content");
```

The target url returns `401 Unauthorized` and it looks like the `NetworkCredentials` haven't been passed through.

The Lambda has been granted the role `AWSLambdaFullAccess`.

When executed locally, this code with the same credentials works as expected.

Comment: Are you getting 401 response from `await httpClient.PostAsync` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes

Comment: The lambda function runs on a completely separate server, how do you expect it to know your windows creds??

Comment: @george By providing them in the NetworkCredential object as shown in the code above. The Lambda function belongs to a private subnet and is able to resolve internal DNS hostnames. I was expecting that based on this, the Elastic Network Interface could also allow Windows Auth.

Comment: can you not pass these creds to the lambda environment variables and reference these in the code?

Comment: @george I'm not sure how that relates to the question?